# How to prevent Android vectors from being reinflated and redrawn to bitmap every time?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am reading this [blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-androids-vector-image-format-vectordrawable-ab09e41d5c68) about `VectorDrawable`. It is mentioned that one of the trade-offs of using vector images is that it is more expensive to render. The blog also states:

> For static vectors, the drawing stage only needs to be performed once and can then be cached to a Bitmap.

But the blog did not explain how to do the caching. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways to do it:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
// depending on the support lib version you may have to use
//  Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

With [Android KTX](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/)

```
val bitmap = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId).toBitmap()
```

Hope it helps